# Open SSL digital signature unable to load key file

Tags: ssl, openssl, digital-signature

I'm looking to create an example of creating a document, digitally signing it, and verifying it. All works fine until I try and verify the signature, all I get is `unable to load key file`

Create a document, which needs an agreement (signature):

```
echo I, Bob, promise to pay Mark £1000 by 1/1/2020 > contract.txt
```

Generate a private key:

```sh
openssl genpkey -algorithm RSA -out private_key.pem -pkeyopt rsa_keygen_bits:2048
```

Generate the public key from the private key:

```sh
openssl rsa -in private_key.pem -RSAPublicKey_out -out public_key.pem
```

Digitally sign the document:

```sh
openssl dgst -sha256 -hex -sign private_key.pem -out signature.sign contract.txt
```

Then if we view the contents of `signature.sign`:

```
RSA-SHA256(contract.txt)= 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
```

To verify the signature:

```
openssl dgst -sha256 -hex -verify public_key.pem -signature signature.sign contract.txt
```

Full script:

```
echo I, Bob, promise to pay Mark £1000 by 1/1/2020 > contract.txt
openssl genpkey -algorithm RSA -out private_key.pem -pkeyopt rsa_keygen_bits:2048
openssl rsa -in private_key.pem -RSAPublicKey_out -out public_key.pem
openssl dgst -sha256 -sign private_key.pem -out signature contract.txt
openssl dgst -sha256 -verify public_key.pem -signature signature contract.txt
```

Thank you!

Comment: Try creating pubkey this way: `openssl pkey -in private_key.pem -pubout -out public_key.pem`

Comment: Yes! Thank you! If you want, answer it and I will set it to correct answer